# Updating meta tags in Nextjs/react application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to make the SEO of a website and I'm not allowed to use any 3rd party libraries.
I want to update the meta description's content with dynamic one. I did everything and it should be working, but to change it I need to reload the page which is not really efficent, I want to do it whenever the page rerenders.

this is the head: I remove most of the code and left only the things you need.

```
const AppHead = ({pageTitle = "", canonicalUrl, metaDescription = ''}) => {
    return (
        <Head>
         <meta name="description" content={metaDescription ? metaDescription : 'Prettyshop'} />
         <title>{pageTitle ? `${pageTitle}` : "Prettyshop"}</title>
        </Head>
```

which is used in the Layout.js

```
function Layout({ pageTitle = "", children, betweenHeaderAndMain, showBrands, canonicalUrl, metaDescription=''}) {
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <AppHead pageTitle={pageTitle} canonicalUrl={canonicalUrl || null} metaDescription={metaDescription} />
            <AddedToCartDialog />
            <LoginDialog />
            <LoginDialog showOnUnauthorized />
            <ErrorDialog />
            <FacebookLogin />
            <Header />
            {betweenHeaderAndMain}
            <main className="container-fluid page-content">{children}</main>
            <Footer showBrands={showBrands ? true : false} />
            <CookiesBar />
            <BackToTop />
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

and here I am passing a value to it:

```
<Layout pageTitle={pageTitle} metaDescription={get(product, 'data.attributes.description', null)? get(product, 'data.attributes.description', null).slice(0,160) : null} betweenHeaderAndMain={<Breadcrumbs className="container-fluid" />}>
            <div className="row product-head">
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-lg-1 col-lg-5">
                    <ImageGallery />
                </div>
        </Layout>
```

As I said everything works fine, but if I reload the page, I want it to update whenever I render the page, not when I reload. How can I update the meta content without reloading the page ?

Comment: And how is the page being re-rendered?

Comment: Whenever you go to different products it rerenders the page but the meta just doesn't update, but when I click refresh it updates it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use state to store the meta description, then update state through setState or props and it will re-render without having to reload.